# Moving Android Eclipse Project to network drive

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been working on my local windows system to develop an android app, all working fine in Eclipse. In order to implement some git versioning in a neat and tidy way alongside all my web-app based projects, I'm trying to move my project to a Linux box, accessible via a samba share over the local network. The samba all works fine.

Can someone guide me or point me to a guide to move a project which also includes class dependencies? Im fairly new to Android, Eclipse and Java so please forgive this novice. Thank you.

I've found this video-tutorial very helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVO0_UdQ_Wg

What I've done:

- exported project (inc dependencies) as general archive file
- Switched workspaces to the network drive.
- Imported existing project from archive file

The errors I'm getting are:

- SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type (SherlockActivity is a class dependency project)
- Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

1. Keep Eclipse work space in local disk.
2. Copy Android project from Eclipse work space to Samba share (assuming the drive name is X), `X:\repo\myproject`.

   - Here, if necessary, delete Eclipse generated folders and files like `bin`, `gen`, `.project`, `.settings`.
3. Pull fresh copy of ActionBarSherlock to `X:\repo\ActionBarSherlock`.
4. Delete `myproject` and `ActionBarSherlock` from Eclipse (via Package Explorer), probably by checking "Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)" as I already have copies on Samba drive.
5. Create new "Android Project from Existing Code" and choose `X:\repo\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock` as a root directory.

   - Here, leave "Copy projects into workspace" unchecked.
6. Create another new "Android Project from Existing Code" and choose `X:\repo\myproject` as a root directory.

   - Here, again, leave "Copy projects into workspace" unchecked.
7. (Probably, `myproject` will fail to build with *"SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type"* error) Right click on `myproject` and choose "Properties" menu, go to "Android" tab and add `actionbarsherlock` from "Add library" field.